# What limits the number of LEDs I can connect to the GPIO?

Tags: gpio, led, electronics

If I just want to connect LEDs to the +3.3v pin and ground pin, what limits the number that I can connect? For example using green LEDs with a voltage drop of 2.2 V, I can only connect one with a resistor in series, because 2.2 + 2.2 V > 3.3 V.

But, in parallel, what stops me from connecting many LEDs? The voltage across them will always be 2.2 V, which is less than 3.3 V?

Comment: The GPIO pins can only source a limited amount of current. If you like to add more leds, you could just add a transistor to allow more current.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect things in parallel, the total amount of current would be the same, limited by the current limiting resistor, therefore one LED will shine quite bright, 5 LEDs would be not so bright and 10+ LEDs will be hard to notice if these are ON or OFF.

If you plan to connect more than 2 LEDs, use a transistor, as `Gerben` noticed in his comment before.